# It is possible to change the format of a column with the "sprintf" function?

Tags: r, format, r-markdown, kable

I am working with the Rmarkdown tool making a report and generating tables with the Kable package.

I am carrying the values of my results in percentage format with the "sprintf" function and everything worked fine so far. The problem is that I have a table with a field that I don't want to be a percentage, however with the function all the values in the table are converted to a percentage.

My code is this:

```
library(kableExtra)
matrix1<-function(matriz_deriv)

z12 <- matrix(sprintf("%.2f%%",100*matrix1), 
            nrow=nrow(matrix1), 
            ncol=ncol(matrix1))

colnames(z12) <- c("Month","value")

kable(z12, "latex", caption = "Matrix1", 
            booktabs = T) %>%
kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "hold_position"))
```

the code works fine, but I just need to apply the percentage to the "Values" column not to the column "Month" and with the sprintf function the percentage is applied to the complete matrix showing the months with percentage.

Do you have any idea how to deal with this?

I have tried several alternatives but without success. I enclose an image of the result of the matrix with the percentages

[image]

Comment: (1) your code is incomplete, syntactically not legal, please update your question with correct code. (2) You explicitly run `sprintf` on the entire matrix, have you tried just running it on one column, such as `matrix1[,2]`?

Comment: @r2evans you are right!. (1) I knew that piece of code was not very intuitive, because it is only the part to generate the table, since the code itself is too long to put. (2) Yes, that was the solution to the problem, only that I was applying it incorrectly, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `sprintf` on the column you want to format:

```r
library(kableExtra)

set.seed(123)
z12 <- matrix(c(1:12, rnorm(12, 0.5, 0.25)), ncol = 2)
colnames(z12) <- c("Month","value")

z12[,2] <- sprintf("%.2f%%", 100*z12[,2])

kable(z12, "html", caption = "Matrix1", 
      booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "hold_position"))
```

[image]